# Problems placing view on top of SlidingPaneLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingpanelayout

I want to place a view via `include` on top of a `SlidingPaneLayout`. In the layout preview of Androíd Studio it is displayed correctly but on my device the view won't show - why?

Here is the complete layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<include layout="@layout/online_state"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_view_spl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/color_background_primary"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <de.timroes.android.listview.EnhancedListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/color_background_primary"
            android:divider="@color/black"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selected_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it...
I have to place the SlidingPaneLayout below the view...
Stupid question... sorry ;)